# How to create ' inside a string wrapped like 'this is my string'

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to extract the json content in my javascript by running it but I am not getting the desired output

My JSON is of the form

```
 var json = [{
        "html": "abc.jpg", //testing this failed
        "col": 1,
        "row": 1,
        "size_y": 2,
        "size_x": 2
    }, {
        "html": "def.jpg", 
        "col": 4,
        "row": 1,
        "size_y": 2,
        "size_x": 2
    },

    {
        "html": "bac.jpg",
        "col": 6,
        "row": 1,
        "size_y": 2,
        "size_x": 2
    },


    {
        "html": "xyz.jpg",
        "col": 1,
        "row": 3,
        "size_y": 1,
        "size_x": 1
    }, {
        "html": "Brand.jpg",
        "col": 4,
        "row": 3,
        "size_y": 1,
        "size_x": 1
    },

    {
        "html": "Brand.jpg",
        "col": 6,
        "row": 3,
        "size_y": 1,
        "size_x": 1
    }

    ];
```

The loop which I am trying to extract content from JSON is

```
for(var index=0;index<json.length;index++) {
    gridster.add_widget('<li class="new" ><button class="delete-widget-button" style="float: right;">-</button><img src="{% static "images/'+json[index].html+'"%}"></li>',json[index].size_x,json[index].size_y,json[index].col,json[index].row);
};
```

What I want is

```
<img src="{% static "images/abc.jpg"%}"> #for first elemet
```

I am sure I am missing some comma in it but not sure where exactly

**Update 1**

The `"{% static 'images/abc.jpg' %}"`  This is exact comma structure I want in my ouput

**Update 2**

Here's a snippet console logging the arguments I'm creating:

```js
var json = [{
    "html": "abc.jpg", //testing this failed
    "col": 1,
    "row": 1,
    "size_y": 2,
    "size_x": 2
  }, {
    "html": "def.jpg",
    "col": 4,
    "row": 1,
    "size_y": 2,
    "size_x": 2
  }, {
    "html": "bac.jpg",
    "col": 6,
    "row": 1,
    "size_y": 2,
    "size_x": 2
  }, {
    "html": "xyz.jpg",
    "col": 1,
    "row": 3,
    "size_y": 1,
    "size_x": 1
  }, {
    "html": "Brand.jpg",
    "col": 4,
    "row": 3,
    "size_y": 1,
    "size_x": 1
  }, {
    "html": "Brand.jpg",
    "col": 6,
    "row": 3,
    "size_y": 1,
    "size_x": 1
  }
];

for (var index = 0; index < json.length; index++) {
  console.log('<li class="new" ><button class="delete-widget-button" style="float: right;">-</button><img src="{% static "images/' + json[index].html + '"%}"></li>', json[index].size_x, json[index].size_y, json[index].col, json[index].row);
};
```

Comment: what's with `"{% static "images/abc.jpg"%}"` , which framework are you using?

Comment: Its syntax for django

Comment: Please read [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: well maybe add your django code as weel?

Comment: The django is at backend.This will just send a request to get image from static/images/abc.jpg

Comment: Shouldn't the html be applied at javascript runtime? Like this maybe: `<img src="{% static "images/'%}"+json[index].html>`

Comment: I mean when I do inspect element it does not shows the path of image which should be what I asked in question

Comment: What i get is    `<img src="/static/images/'%2Bjson%5Bindex%5D.html%2B'">`

Comment: @Rookie_123 That is because Django executes before JavaScript.

Comment: This isn't going to  work in the manner you're attempting. The `{% static "images/abc.jpg"%}` literal is a server side construct which depends on whatever framework you use. It will not be interpreted on the client, which is the case of your problem. To achieve what you need I'd suggest you use an AJAX request to build the HTML you require (based on the server templating you're using) and then return that to your UI.

Comment: ^ with tha in mind I'd suggest you read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) which covers the fundamental differences and how it affects the page lifecycle

Comment: When I do that for other instances in the page(Not for json) the image is loaded.So I tried to apply same logic here

Comment: This `<img src="{% static 'images/abc.png' %}" alt="logo"/> ` loads perfect image

Comment: May be here the logic could be different.Thanks for giving the link

Comment: `"html": "def.jpg,", ` sure the comma in `def.jpg,` is intentional?

Comment: No that should not be there But still the abc.jpg should work fine.Updated the question by removing ,

Comment: @connexo my desired output is of the form  "{% static 'images/abc.jpg' %}"   Note the comma pattern

Comment: Its not same what I am getting

Comment: There is no comma in your desired output. This, and only this is referred to as comma in the English language: `,`

Comment: I am sorry apostrophe I wanted to say.The " and ' pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with the use of quotes. Fix it be prefixing your inner `'` characters with a slash `\'` (this is called *escaping*):

```
gridster.add_widget('<li class="new" ><button class="delete-widget-button" style="float: right;">-</button><img src="{% static \'images/'+json[index].html+'\'%}"></li>',json[index].size_x,json[index].size_y,json[index].col,json[index].row);
```

```js
var json = [{
    "html": "abc.jpg", //testing this failed
    "col": 1,
    "row": 1,
    "size_y": 2,
    "size_x": 2
  }, {
    "html": "def.jpg",
    "col": 4,
    "row": 1,
    "size_y": 2,
    "size_x": 2
  }, {
    "html": "bac.jpg",
    "col": 6,
    "row": 1,
    "size_y": 2,
    "size_x": 2
  }, {
    "html": "xyz.jpg",
    "col": 1,
    "row": 3,
    "size_y": 1,
    "size_x": 1
  }, {
    "html": "Brand.jpg",
    "col": 4,
    "row": 3,
    "size_y": 1,
    "size_x": 1
  }, {
    "html": "Brand.jpg",
    "col": 6,
    "row": 3,
    "size_y": 1,
    "size_x": 1
  }
];

for (var index = 0; index < json.length; index++) {
  console.log('<img src="{% static \'images/' + json[index].html + '\' %}">');
};
```

Comment: It says  `Could not parse the remainder: '\'images/'+json[index].html+' from '\'images/'+json[index].html+`

Comment: In that case the problem is related to `gridster.add_widget` whatever that is, however this answer gives you the changes necessary to create your desired output.

Comment: Yeah same may be the case Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is returning this

```
<li class="new" ><button class="delete-widget-button" style="float: right;">-</button><img src="{% static "images/abc.jpg"%}"></li> 2 2 1 1
<li class="new" ><button class="delete-widget-button" style="float: right;">-</button><img src="{% static "images/def.jpg,"%}"></li> 2 2 4 1
<li class="new" ><button class="delete-widget-button" style="float: right;">-</button><img src="{% static "images/bac.jpg"%}"></li> 2 2 6 1
<li class="new" ><button class="delete-widget-button" style="float: right;">-</button><img src="{% static "images/xyz.jpg"%}"></li> 1 1 1 3
<li class="new" ><button class="delete-widget-button" style="float: right;">-</button><img src="{% static "images/Brand.jpg"%}"></li> 1 1 4 3
<li class="new" ><button class="delete-widget-button" style="float: right;">-</button><img src="{% static "images/Brand.jpg"%}"></li> 1 1 6 3
```

You might have extra comma here: "images/def.jpg," at index=1

Comment: "{% static 'images/abc.jpg' %}" is what I want.Exactly same comma structure

Answer (score 0):

if you replace gridster.add_widget with console.log, the output looks fine:

```
<img src="{% static "images/abc.jpg"%}">
```

Try adding space before closing tag:

```
..json[index].html+'" %}"></li>
                     ^here
```